# MSMQ won't enable on windows 7 machine

Tags: msmq, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to enable MSMQ on my development computer (running Windows 7).

I go to turn windows features on or off -> Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) Server Core -> Check MSMQ Active Directory Domain Services Integration AND MSMQ HTTP Support.

When I click OK, I get the error "An Error has occurred.  Not all of the features were successfully changed." -> Click OK -> "You must restart your computer to apply these changes".

I've clicked Restart Now and Restart later and no matter what, same issue every time.

If I selected Restart later and go into Services...I see Message Queuing (stopped), and if I try to start the service, I get the error "Windows could not start the Message Queuing service on Local Computer.  Error 0x80070005: Access denied."

I checked my privileges and I am an Admin on the machine.  Just to be safe, I even logged into the machine as the actual Administrator.  Same scenario.

Furthermore, when I go into the Event Viewer, I check the Application logs.  I have an error with MSMQ as the Source.  EventID: 2076, Error: The logger files cannot be initialized.  The file QMLog in the Msmq\Storage folder is corrupted or absent.  Error 0x80070005: Access denied.

If I check the System Logs, I see another error with the source being Service Control manager.  Error eventId: 7023, Error:  The Message Queuing service terminated with the following error:  %%-2147024891

When I look up the error codes on Microsoft, there is NOTHING.

Comment: -2147024891 is also 0x80070005. "I checked my privileges and I am an Admin on the machine." That is not relevant - MSMQ runs as a service under a System account, not your admin account. If MSMQ is  getting "Access Denied" then it doesn't have permission to do what it needs to do, it's really as simple as that. In this case it means the Windows\System32\Msmq\Storage folder is locked down too tight - can happen through draconian company security policies being applied, for example.

Comment: My machine is the only one out of 10 other developers that has this issue.  All machines are built the exact same way, same security, etc.  Are you aware of what I should try and do to resolve this?  I have gotten nowhere with Microsoft help, this is the most feedback I've gotten.  So thanks.

Comment: If the machines were all built the same, they would all behave the same :-) Have you checked the permissions on the Windows\System32\Msmq\Storage folder and compared with a working machine?

Comment: permissions are the same :/

Comment: OK, have you tried focusing on QMLOG's permissions? Have you looked at this article? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733510.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this - not sure how it came about as I always had AD integration turned ON for my MSMQ (as I needed it) but somewhere along the line, it got turned off and I couldn't turn it back on again via Control Panel - I would get the error behaviour (and restart!) that the OP describes. To fix it, I accessed my machine via the AD services manager app on one of our domain servers and deleted the "msmq" object that was under it.

I restarted my local MSMQ service on my machine AND rebooted (not sure which or both was required) and then when I checked my local registry entries, it indicated I was correctly running in AD mode once again. Everything started to work again after that.

This link was helpful in giving me the right direction to go in: [Technet MSMQ delete stale objects article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733521%28WS.10%29.aspx#_B00949DE_017E_4E2E_A724_14A99314CCAE)